# convert specific rows of pandas dataframe into multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

here is my DataFrame:

```
          0     1        2
0 0      0.0  20.0      NaN
  1      1.0  21.0      NaN
  2      2.0  22.0      NaN
  ID     NaN   NaN  11111.0
  Year   NaN   NaN   2011.0
1 0      3.0  23.0      NaN
  1      4.0  24.0      NaN
  2      5.0  25.0      NaN
  3      6.0  26.0      NaN
  ID     NaN   NaN  11111.0
  Year   NaN   NaN   2012.0
```

i want to convert the 'ID' and 'Year' rows to dataframe Index with 'ID' being level=0 and 'Year' being level=1. I tried using stack() but still cannot figure it .

Edited: my desired output should look like below:

```
                      0     1 
  11111  2011 0      0.0  20.0
              1      1.0  21.0
              2      2.0  22.0
         2012 0      3.0  23.0
              1      4.0  24.0
              2      5.0  25.0
              3      6.0  26.0
```

Comment: Row indices? for which rows? Can you show your desired outcome?

Comment: What's the logic in the data? `ID` and `Year` repeat every so often? Does it always follow the rows it identifies?

Comment: @ako: the need for this sort of processing arose from another operation done on the dataframe. in this case, the columns (0 & 1) had list values like [20,21,22] which were stacked, but doing so gave rise to the problem referred to in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df1 = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['ID', 'Year']], '2']
dfs = df1.unstack()
dfi = df1.index
dfn = df.drop(dfi).drop('2', axis=1).unstack()

dfn.set_index([dfs.ID, dfs.Year]).stack()
```

[image]